# Can't log in to chat - it logs me with the wrong user

Tags: support, chat, login, users, auto-login

Tested also in a new browser with no cookies/cache. I can login sucessfully to any site and meta site of the web, but whenever I try to login to any chat, it autologins with a different user https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/11558/jynus instead of https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/30545/jynus (this user). I logged-in through Google authentication.

I tried to delete the old one, but it was no solution, logging out and logging in from the chat doesn't work, as as soon as I login, it authenticates with the new user. If I log out directly to the chat, with some of the links provided in other answers/login support text, it works (if it is the first login ever) temporarily, but as soon as I log into a room, I get changed to the other user. As a result, I cannot talk even in my own created rooms.

I've read the [support page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/help) thoroughly, no success (posting here was the last resort).

Tested on Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I managed to login to the chat on the stackoverflow domain, but not on the stackexchange domain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Congratulations, you were a proud owner of two different accounts on Stack Exchange (the Q&A sites, not chat). I merged them together and removed the chat user associated with the old site profile.

Try again - you should get linked up with the right profile. Let me know if that doesn't happen.

Comment: Thank you, login delegation is both a blessing and a curse!

Comment: @jynus Happy to help. :)